# Getting the local IP address in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, lan, ip-address

I am trying to get my locally assigned IP address from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with `ifconfig` and what I'm getting is my external IP address (in other words, it's the same IP I see on [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com))

When running `ifconfig eth0`, `inet addr` shows my external IP address instead of the local address.

How do I get my local IP address ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `ifconfig eth0` returns an externally routeable IP address, you're almost certainly not behind any NAT.  `ifconfig` has no way to know what any non-NATed IP address would be, it can only report the IP address actually associated with the interface.

Why do you think that the IP address shown is incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

`ip addr` shows you every address your machine has. That includes ipv4, ipv6, mac, link-local and global, avahi…

If you don't see an rfc1918 private address, it means you aren't behind a NAT. Your router is acting like a modem and doesn't have an ip address of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a router for it: so the router will have the public ip and your box will have its local ip delivered by DHCP.

Just out of curiosity: why aren't you ok with external ip? Security issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ip route`
The first or second match with this regex is your local IP:

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

If this returns also your external IP, then I think you don't have a router....